# Return first date (Sunday) of a particular week in SQL redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to set a WHERE filter where only results with dates after last week Sunday (including last week Sunday) are returned. What I have at the moment is:

date_part(w,GETDATE())

This gives me the current week number. How do I know find the first date of this week number (43) so the 18th of October?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This returns weeks starting on Mondays, which is pretty standard:

```
date_trunc('week', current_date)
```

If you want Sunday to start the week, then:

```
date_trunc('week', current_date + interval '1 day') - interval '1 day'
```

Note:  If today is Sunday, then it returns today's date.  If you want last Sunday's date in that case, just use:

```
date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '1 day'
```